# Python how to update a sql server from a dictionary?

Tags: python, sql

I have an INSERT statement that looks like:

```
query = "INSERT TABLE ({columns}) VALUES ({value_placeholders})".format(
    columns=", ".join(my_dict.keys()),
    value_placeholders=", ".join(["?"] * len(my_dict)),
)

cursor.execute(query, list(my_dict.values()))
```

How do I turn it into an UPDATE statement?

I've got this so far...

```
query = "UPDATE TABLE SET ({columns}) ({value_placeholders}) WHERE ID = ({id})".format(
    columns=", ".join(my_dict.keys()),
    value_placeholders=", ".join(["?"] * len(my_dict)),
    id=id
)

cursor.execute(query, list(my_dict.values()))
```

Not sure how to join the key/value pairs in the dictionary to make it in the right format.

Edit:

```
my_dict ={
 'key1': '1',
 'key2': 'whatever',
 'key3': Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:27:34.883683354'),
 'key4': 'blabla',
 'key5': Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:27:34.883882086'),
 'ID': 11
}
```

Comment: could you show us what `my_dict` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the generated query string that you can use

```py
# Imports
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
from datetime import datetime

# Input dict
my_dict ={
 'key1': '1',
 'key2': 'whatever',
 'key3': Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:27:34.883683354'),
 'key4': 'blabla',
 'key5': Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:27:34.883882086'),
 'ID': 11
}
# generate key/pair array
arr = []
for key,value in my_dict.items():
    if type(value) is Timestamp: # Handle TimeStamps
        arr.append("{key} = {value}".format(key=key, value=value.timestamp()))
    elif type(value) is int: # Handle Integers
        arr.append("{key} = {value}".format(key=key, value=value))
    else: # Default Handler
        arr.append("{key} = '{value}'".format(key=key, value=value))
# generate string from key/pair array
data = ", ".join(arr)

# format SQL string
id = 1
table_name = 'users'
query = "UPDATE {table_name} SET {data} WHERE id = {id};".format(table_name=table_name, data=data, id=id)

# Call Query
cursor.execute(query)
```

[Read More Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: I'm getting error in the values with strings ```ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near...```

Comment: @Mitch please look  at the code again, I've made an update to this `"{key} = '{value}'".format(key=key, value=value)` i added quotes to the value

Comment: now it fails on the datetime ```DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLExecDirectW)')```. I'm guessing because it passes the datetime object as a str because of the quotes?

Comment: @Mitch try my updated code now